# How to filter formula fields in SOQL or APEX

Tags: apex, soql

Please Help!!!

I would like to retrieve all the fields except formula

Comment: Build dynamic query and append only createable fields to query text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use `getCalculatedFormula` and `isCalculated` to check field is formula or not and create dynamic soql

[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isCalculated)

Below is an example for Account

```
List<String> lstFields = new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectField fld: Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()){
    if(fld.getDescribe().getCalculatedFormula() == null && !fld.getDescribe().isCalculated())
    {
       system.debug('----field--'+fld.getDescribe().getName());
       lstFields.add(fld.getDescribe().getName()); 
    } 
}
Database.query('SELECT '+String.join(lstFields, ', ')+ ' FROM Account' );
```

Comment: When I am using this I am getting below error
SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: CustomFields

Comment: @Rajesh are you accessing any formula field ?

Comment: Yes...I am accessing the formula field.
I have attached the piece of code above

Comment: @Rajesh if you are accessing formua field then don't filter the formula field in soql . and please ask a new question if you have any issue. this question is closed

Comment: ok thank you...